# copy move forgery detection stuck with algorithm

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement the paper detection of copy move forgery using histogram of oriented gradients.

The algorithm is:

1. Divide the image into overlapping blocks.
2. Calculate feature vectors for each block and store them in a matrix.
3. Sorting the matrix lexicographically
4. Using block matching to identify forged regions.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276518650_Detection_of_copy-move_image_forgery_using_histogram_of_orientated_gradients

I am stuck with the 3rd step and can't proceed.

The code I have implemented is:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
%read image
img = imread('006_F.png');
img=rgb2gray(img);
img=imresize(img, 1/4);
figure(1); 
imshow(img);

b=16; %block size
nrc=5; %no. of rows to check
td=416; %threshold
[r, c]=size(img);%Rows and columns;
column=(r-b+1)*(c-b+1);
M= zeros(column,4);
Mi = zeros(1,2);
i=1;
disp('starting extraction of features');
for r1 = 1:r-b+1
for c1 = 1:c-b+1
% Extract each block
B = img(r1:r1+b-1,c1:c1+b-1);

features = extractHOGFeatures(B);%extracting features
M(i, :) = features;
Mi(i,:) = [r1 c1];
i=i+1;
end
end
[S, index] = sortrows(M , [ 1 2 3 4]);
P= zeros(1,6);
b2=r-b+1;
disp('Finding Duplicates');
for i = 1:column
    iv = index(i);
    xi=mod(iv,b2) + 1;
    yi=ceil(iv/b2);
    j = i+1;    
    while j < column && abs(i - j) < 5
        jv=index(j);
        xj=mod(jv,b2) + 1;
        yj=ceil(jv/b2);

        z=sqrt(power(xi-xj,2) + power(yi-yj,2));
        % only process those whose size is above Nd 

        if z > 16
            offset = [xi-xj yi-yj];
            P = [P;[xi yi xj yj xi-xj yi-yj]];  

        end          
       j = j + 1;
    end
end
rows = size(P,1);
P(:,6) = P(:,6) - min(P(:,6));
P(:,5) = P(:,5) - min(P(:,5));

maxValP = max(P(:,6)) + 1;
P(:,5) = maxValP .* P(:,5) + P(:,6);
mostfrequentval = mode(P(:,5));


disp('Creating Image');
idx = 2;
% Create a copy of the image and mask it

RI = img;
while idx < rows 
  x1 = P(idx,1);
  y1 = P(idx,2);
  x2 = P(idx,3);
  y2 = P(idx,4);

  if (P(idx,5) == mostfrequentval)
    RI(y1:y1,x1:x1) = 0;
    RI(y2:y2,x2:x2) = 0;

  end
  idx = idx + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Could you precise what " lexicographically" means? Is that what you are trying to do with "sortrows"?

Comment: the definition of lexicographical sorting is the dictionary sort.. and yes thats what i am trying to do with sortrows.. you can refer the paper on the link to help.. thanx in advance

Comment: sortrows should work, just precise which column contains the strings to be sorted as the second input argument.

Comment: the contents of the matrix are feature vectors.. which are numbers.. and identical or similar vectors represent similar (forged blocks)

Comment: There is something I do not understand:
You say: "lexicographical sorting is the dictionary sort"
And then: "contents of the matrix are feature vectors.. which are numbers"
Could you please provide a sample matrix with several rows and the result you expect from the sorting procedure?

Comment: @Eskapp sir.. the matrix contains numbers like.. 0.426 .148 .4896 .5761 in a row.. and the no. of rows is equal to total no. of overlapping blocks.. now what we have to do is to sort the matrix in such a way that the idential or similar vectors (rows) are in the vicinity of each other.. and then we have to calculate the  distance between those (blocks)neighbouring rows(5 rows in the paper) and the compare it with a threshold distance if the distance is greater than threshold whe have to mark those as forged regions.

Comment: So here, you need to know what "similar" means quantitatively. Are vectors similar is they have the same euclidean norm for instance? I honestly don't have time to go through the paper...

Comment: they are similar if they have the same values.. or values very close.. as far as i have understood..

Comment: detection can be achieved through
lexicographical sorting of the rows in matrix A, such that the features of the duplicated block pairs appear successively.
In this case, the lexicographically sorted matrix is denoted as b.
This study employed block matching to match corresponding blocks and identify regions that are likely to have been
forged. In the proposed scheme, corresponding blocks are identified by estimating the Euclidean distances of the feature
vectors.

Comment: In order to accurately identify the forged region, the distance threshold Td and the threshold of similarity Ts should
be predetermined. There are distinct similarities in the feature vectors of blocks with overlapping pixels; therefore, only
blocks with a distance larger than the length of block L are compared. In this manner, distance threshold Td is defined according
to the length of block L.

Comment: @Eskapp.. i can understand.. and i really appreciate you taking out time to help..

Comment: A first step could be to compute the Euclidean distances of all your features vectors with respect to a given feature vector. And then sort the matrix with respect to this distance. At least, duplicated vectors will show successively... But definitively not the best solution to your problem...

Comment: first step according to me is to sort the matrix.. and then for each row compare 5 rows for the euclidian distance.. and then if distance greater than threshold segment out them.. but not really sure how to do it..

Comment: Yeah, but with respect to what do you sort the matrix? This is up to you to know and then you can figure out how to tell Matlab to do it. There are multiple ways of sorting a matrix (w.r.t its first column, or its second column, or w.r.t the norm of each row,...)

Comment: i am trying to figure that out.. i think it should be the 1st column..but the result i am getting after the segmentation is..almost the whole.. image is blackened.. if you could take out sometime and refer to the paper.. i shall be really obliged..

Comment: i have edited my code.. as i have proceeded.. the result i am getting is only a few points.. are segmented out as forged.. not the region which should be.

Answer (score 0):

After going through some references indicated in the paper you are working on (ref. [8] and [20]):

The lexicographic sorting is the equivalent of the alphabetical one, for numbers i.e., [1 1 1 1] < [1 1 2 1] < [2 3 4 5] < [2 4 4 5]

So, in your case, you case use the function `sortrows()` in the following way:

```
A = [1 1 1 1;1 1 1 2;1 1 1 4;1 2 2 2; 1 2 2 1; 1 4 6 3; 2 3 4 5; 2 3 6 6]; % sample matrix
[B,idx] = sortrows(A,[1 2 3 4]); % Explicit notation but it is the Matlab default setting so equivalent to sortrows(A)
```

It means: Sort the rows of A by first looking at the first column and, in case of equality, looking at the second one, and so on.

If your are looking for a reverse order, you specify '-' before the number of the column.

So in the end, your code is good and if the results are not as expected it has to come from another step of the implementation...

Edit: the parameter `idx` records the original index of the sorted rows.

Comment: hi.. thanx.. after this i think i am going to need the indexes of the rows.. to get the starting point of the block so that i can calculate the euclidian distance between the blocks..

Comment: I edited my answer so that you get the indexes of the sorted rows.

Comment: i have edited my code.. as i have proceeded.. the result i am getting is only a few points.. are segmented out as forged.. not the region which should be..

Comment: Then this is not a programming question anymore. Can be because of the data, because of the features,...

Comment: but the features are calculated as mentioned in the paper.. also using the predefined function in matlb..

Comment: also i tried to use pca features.. instead of hog.. still isnt working.. so might be some problem with the code..

Comment: With the same data as them? With all the exact same parameters? (Matlab has many default parameters for each function). If it is the case, then my only advice is to contact the authors. It is unfortunately pretty common that a personal implementation of a research paper doesn't bring the expected results when all the parameters are not specified or when the data is different from the one used in the experiments...

Comment: i have edit the function according to the parameters required.. and used the predefined one too.. ive tried to contact the authors.. but didnt get a reply.. you sure the code is fine..?

Comment: I honestly cannot go over the entire paper and its implementation. It is not the point of Stack Overflow which is for technical programming questions. For conceptual questions, you should look at other Stack Exchange websites. My best advice is that you go step by step through your code and check it yourself. Maybe the paper has a flow and you can fix it by thinking of what you want to achieve with each of the steps. But once again, we are out of the programming task itself.

Comment: thanx.. you have been a great help..  :)